# Is there any tool to count the number of round trips for a HTTP request?

Tags: http, https, roundtrip

I want some tool to show/check that there are actually less round trips when a request is made using TLS 1.3 then when using TLS 1.2 (all over HTTPS). Is there any tool to check that? I'm not being able to get that neither from Chrome's DevTools nor from cURL.

Note: I do not want to measure the Round Trip Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean TLS (transport layer securiy), not [LTS](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/LTS).

With a proper operating system you could simply inject latency using [traffic shaping](https://www.lartc.org/howto/) and measure it with a stop clock. But personally I'd just look at the packets with Wireshark.

Comment: Just edited it, thanks for the correction I definitely didn't mean Long Term Support :).